# Thread safe: Item with the same key already added

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have the following code, that takes input of a byte array and rebuilds the original JSON string before it was decomposed into bytes.

I get an error that says that an item with the same key has already been added.

```
 public class HandleAccessResponse
    {

        private static byte[] tempStore;
        private static Dictionary<String, int> authchunkID = new Dictionary<String, int>();
        private static ResponseModel responseModel = new ResponseModel();
        private static object lockObj = new object();

        public static ResponseModel HandleResponse(byte[] response)
        {
            byte[] temp;
            byte[] pos = new byte[4];
            byte[] chunk_num = new byte[4];
            byte[] original = new byte[4];
            byte[] guid = new byte[32];

            int position, chunkNumber, ogSize;
            int start = 0, end = 0;
            int chunkSize = 0;

            string theGuid;

            if (response == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Request not set");

            }

            chunkSize = response.Length;

            for (var a = 0; a < 4; a++)
            {
                pos[a] = response[a];
            }

            if (pos == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Position not set");
            }
            else
            {
                position = BitConverter.ToInt32(pos, 0);
            }

            int count = 0;
            for (var b = 4; b < 8; b++)
            {
                chunk_num[count] = response[b];
                count++;
            }

            if (chunk_num == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Chunk number not set");
            }
            else
            {
                chunkNumber = BitConverter.ToInt32(chunk_num, 0);
            }

            int count2 = 0;
            for (var c = 8; c < 12; c++)
            {
                original[count2] = response[c];
                count2++;
            }

            if (original == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Original size not passed");
            }
            else
            {
                ogSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(original, 0);
            }

            // retrieve the guid in the last four bytes
            int count3 = 0;
            for (var d = 12; d < 44; d++)
            {
                guid[count3] = response[d];
                count3++;
            }

            if (guid == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Guid not set");
            }
            else
            {
                theGuid = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(guid);
            }

            lock (lockObj)
            {
                if (isSaved(theGuid))
                {
                    if (incrementCount(authchunkID, theGuid))
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                    }
                }
                else
                {                 
                    authchunkID.Add(theGuid, 1);

                    responseModel.chunkID.Add(theGuid, 1);

                    tempStore = new byte[ogSize];
                }
            }


            temp = new byte[response.Length - 44];


            Array.Copy(response, 44, temp, 0, temp.Length);

            int x = value_of_x(position);

            if (x == 0)
            {
                temp.CopyTo(tempStore, start);
            }
            else
            {
                int subtract = (x * 4036);
                end = subtract;

                temp.CopyTo(tempStore, end);
            }


            if (authchunkID[theGuid] == chunkNumber)
            {



                var authoriseRspMsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(tempStore, 0, tempStore.Length);



                var authoriseRsp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthoriseResp>(authoriseRspMsg);


                if (authoriseRsp.transaction != null)
                {

                    authoriseRespModel.authoriseResp = authoriseRsp;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Authorise message is empty");
                }
                authchunkID.Remove(theGuid);
            }

            return responseModel;
        }
        private static Boolean incrementCount(Dictionary<string, int> aeschunkID, String guid)
        {
            Boolean isUpdated = false;

            if (aeschunkID.ContainsKey(guid))
            {
                int value = aeschunkID[guid];
                value++;

                aeschunkID[guid] = value;
                responseModel.chunkID[guid] = value;
                isUpdated = true;

                return isUpdated;
            }

            return isUpdated;

        }
        private static Boolean isSaved(String guid)
        {       
                Boolean hasBeen = false;
                if (guid.Length > 0 && !(guid == null))
                {
                    if (authchunkID.ContainsKey(guid))
                    {
                        hasBeen = true;
                    }
                    return hasBeen;
                }
                return hasBeen;            
        }

        private static int value_of_x(int position)
        {
            int x;
            if (position == 0)
            {
                x = 0;
                return x;
            }
            else if (position == 1)
            {
                x = position;
                return x;
            }
            else
            {
                x = position;
                return x;
            }
        }
    }
```

The code runs the first time then a few seconds later it breaks with an error message saying an item with the same key was already added. I have tried adding a lock to the section it is break in with the "**lockObj**", but that does not seem to work

Comment: Use `dictionary[key] = value` instead of `dictionary.Add(key, value)`. It will prevent the error. And make sure your keys are __unique__.

Comment: Even if the lock worked it would be a poor solution because I don't see multiple threads. The error is clear: You're trying to add something with a certain key but an item with that key has already been added. Why are you adding the same key again?

Comment: @alex That will prevent the error because it is assignment and not adding. It will just overwrite and may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: please provide more information to the context of "multithreading". Are you running this code in parallel in several threads? and at least 2 of them are trying to insert the same key?

Comment: Even if you use `dictionary[key] = value`, something is likely still wrong. Do you expect to have duplicate keys? If you don't, then updating the value in the dictionary instead of adding means that you'll be replacing the value, which could mean losing the old value. If you don't expect duplicate keys then I'd keep using `Add` so that you know if something is wrong with your logic, and you can fix that instead of making the error go away.

Comment: The logic problems will also be easier to spot if you simplify the code. There are cases like `pos` and `response` where it looks like you're just copying from one variable to another. `value_of_x` does exactly what it says - it returns the argument passed to it. If x = 1, it returns 1. If x = 0, it returns x. Otherwise it returns x. Why does that function exist? Any excess like that can make the code more complicated, which in turn makes it harder to spot mistakes.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, that's why I ask the OP to be careful about key uniqueness. Word '__unique__' is bold in my previous comment.